# React JS onChange function of Material UI 'number' TextField uses previous value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an onChange function on this element:

```
<TextField id="rowinput" type="number" 
           defaultValue={this.defaultRows} // defaultrRows = 1
           inputProps={{ min: "1", max:"5"}}
           onChange={this.handleRows}>
</TextField>
```

This is the function:

```
handleRows = ev => {
        let newrows = ev.target.value;
        let newcount = newrows * this.state.cols;
        this.setState( {rows: newrows, panelcount: newcount} )
        console.log("Row Count: " + this.state.rows);
        console.log("Total Count: " + this.state.panelcount);
}
```

What this should do is take the value of the input field when the up and down arrows are clicked, and update the state. However, I've found that when the console statement in the handler prints its result, the number used is one step behind.

As you can see, on page load it starts with a default value of 1 (as does the cols value it is referencing), and so when the up arrow is clicked, the value changes to 2 and it should print out:

> Row Count: 2

> Total Count: 2

When I print the temporary variables it prints 2 and 2, but when I use the state call here, it prints 1 and 1.
Here for example, I increased the value up to 5, and you can see the console never logged higher than 4:

[image]

[image]

Is the state update called asynchronously? How can the temporary variables be correct but calling this.state.rows is one iteration behind?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using setState the state is not actually updated until the next render. Your console log is in the same function and occurs before the re-render after state is updated. If you were to do the console.log outside of the function you will see that the state is updated.

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for your answer. You are right as I moved the console.log into the render function and it works. Just for my understanding though, when I was learning the basics I read that setState automatically calls render. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: You're correct in your understanding that setState calls the re-render. In your case the handleRows function is called -> setState is called -> then you log in the console. Since the console.log is in that same function it is still taking in the old value of state because it was called in the render prior to the state update and does not yet know about the updated state. setState also has a callback (will run after state update) built in as the second parameter: this.setState( {rows: newrows, panelcount: newcount}, () => console.log(...) )  if you want to give that a try.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks very much for taking the time to explain :)